# i dont know why this error: Invalid Scopes: user_likes. This message is only shown to developers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport-facebook

when i try to login, appears the message, but if i erase the scope, works, but i need the information.

This is my code:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook',
passport.authenticate('facebook',{scope: ['user_likes']}));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
passport.authenticate('facebook',{failureRedirect:'/'}),
function (req,res) {
    res.redirect('/');
}
);
```

Comment: Most likely because Facebook have not approved the permission for your app

Comment: my app si not online yet, so i cant taste it until facebook approved?, my app si developing now.